# Web.config 500 block ipaddress - Internal server error

Tags: asp.net

This is my web.config which has some tags for blocking Ipaddress

```
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
  <files>
    <clear/>
   
    <add value="Default.aspx"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<security>

  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
   
    <clear/>
   
    <add ipAddress="21.2.22.2" allowed="true"/>
    
  </ipSecurity>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

So my intention is to block any other IP except the above.
The above is the only IP address I want the website to be accessible from .
But this is the error I am receiving

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

My website is hosted on lunar pages. So the IP address is the client address, it shouldn't have anything to do with the hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can do that at the web.config level unless the "IP and Domain Restrictions" role is installed on the server itself. See an article here http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I use it on a site where I don't have access to IIS. It works successfully in blocking individual IP addresses. It probably could be modified to only allow certain IP addresses.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnIPAddressBlockingHttpModuleForASPNETIn9Minutes.aspx